# Client-side image manipulation best practices

Tags: django, image-processing, web-applications, client-side, image-uploading

I'm developing a web application based on Django which will allow the user to upload their images, crop them, apply some filters and then send them to my server as a list of all edited images, but I don't know the best way to handle this.
This is what I got so far:

- The user upload an image using a form.
- I save the image to my server and redirect the user to a view that shows all the uploaded images.
- When the user clicks an image, I send the user to a page where I use **JCrop** to allow the user to crop the image and save it. When the user save the image, it is sent to my server again and save it.

My question is, what is the best way to handle this? Should I upload the images and edit them on memory and then send the list of edited images to my server?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you already have the original image, you could retrieve that from a file, apply the correct crop, then either replace the file or saved the manipulated copy. If you don't want to do it on the server, there may be some libraries that only send the updated file form the client, but they might not work in all environments.

Comment: Yeah, but what if the user uploads 24 images and then logout from the app? I don't want to store those images. The images that the user uploads will be used to assemble a final product.

Comment: We crop all images client-side in Javascript. Only when the user wants to save the result do we upload it. I would *strongly* recommend this approach.

Comment: Hey Thane, how can I do that? How I manipulate the image without store it first on my server?